# Concentration for the maximum magnitude entry for a random matrix

Tags: random-matrices, concentration-of-measure

For $A \in {\mathbb R}^{n \times m}$ let,

$$ \vert A \vert _{\max} = \max_{\substack{i=1,\ldots, n\\ j = 1,\ldots,m}} \vert A_{ij} \vert $$

- Are there any concentration inequalities known about this ``max-"norm of a matrix?

Comment: What are the assumptions on the entries of $A$ ?

Comment: Make any reasonable assumption about the random matrix $A$ :)

Comment: Weel, if absolute values of the entries are iid with CDF $F$, then of course $\mathbb P(\|A\|_{\text{max}} > x) = 1-\mathbb P(\|A\|_{\text{max}} \le x) = 1-F(x)^{mn}$, from which you'll get concentration if $F$ is light-tailed.